# Wine unmet dependencies error

Tags: apt, wine, dependencies, ppa, repository

The other day, I tried to install something, but I can't remember what it was at this point. Now I can no longer install anything because of the errors listed in these pictures. Someone, please, please help me! Thank you ever so kindly!

Error in removing wine (`dpkg -l | grep i386`, Highlighted the file that is not allowing me to install anything else because of "unmet dependacies"):

[image: ERROR IN REMOVING WINE 1.6]

Comment: Could you please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter you can either 1) select, copy & paste the terminal content or 2) [save it to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you try to install a package? Could you please include the *full verbatim* error message? What's the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: Sorry, but a picture isn't even a good idea in the first place, much less yellow/red text over a transparent background over a noisy background. Text would be really helpful, because I cannot read any of that.

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and type

```
  sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

If it doesn't help then do this

```
  sudo apt autoremove <packagename>
```

If this doesn't help then you
Need an internet connection.Type in terminal

```
  sudo apt-get autoclean
```

remove sources.list file.and create new sources.list...

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then, type in

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

[image]
This will open software-properties-gtk and a newsources.list will be created automatically.

Then change the server to US or to any other server of your choice. You must enable repositories from the new dialog in order to create new sources.list.

Tick all the boxes then click on Revert then click close.

Need to restore default repositories

```
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

(it is good practice to backup this file before installing to recover if such things happen)

Now install anything!